# How can I view an argo rollout deployment on aws eks locally on the argo rollout dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-rollouts

After manually deploying argo rollout to aws eks, I ran kubectl argo rollout dashboard locally.

Usually, the app executed locally uses the cloud address, which is a domain or IP, to bring the corresponding information.

However, this argo rollout dashboard If you just run the dashboard after deployment without any other settings, the information of the app being rolled out from kubernetes is fetched and displayed.

I'm curious how to get that information and display it.